# "used to" or "used for", which one should I use when I want to explain what's a tool for?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

this question comes from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535509/is-there-a-way-to-compute-the-cluster-std-of-the-dataset-generated-by-make-blobs)

> make_blobs() is used for Generating isotropic Gaussian blobs for
>   clustering.

when I want to talk what the function make_blobs() is for, should I "used to" or "used for"?

Comment: either works. the question is what the verb after it will be "... to do your homework" vs "...for do**ing** your homework". The sentence could have easily been `make_blobs() is used to Generate isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering.`

Answer (score 3):

*Is used **for** generat**ing*** or *is used **to** generat**e***. A version like '*is used to generating*' won't work since it would mean someone *in the habit* of generating something.